# Removing line that only contain one unique character in BASH

Tags: bash, shell

Needing to filter a file of all lines that only contain one character (can be repeated several times) or in other words every line needs to contain at least 2 unique characters. I know every line will only contain one word and every word is lowercase.

File:

```
hello
world
pppppppp
foo
bar
iiiiiiii
blue
red
oooooooo
io
u
```

Output:

```
hello
world
foo
bar
blue
red
io
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried ?  Wecome to SO. Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then `edit` your question to SO's community guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: You accepted the answer of @randomir. Is it correct you do not want to filter empty lines and lines with only dots or other special characters (`===`, `%`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to do with `grep`:

```
grep -vE '^\w$|^(\w)\1+$' file
```

This filters out (`-v`) all lines that are either (1) a single alphanumeric character (`^\w$`), or (2) one alphanumeric character repeated at least twice (`^(\w)\1+$`).

To filter-out lines with a single, or a repeated single character (as suggested in comments by @janos and @WalterA):

```
grep -vE '^(.)\1*$' file
```